# What is some of the most common ways to consume REST API's in a .NET environment? C# or JS or another language?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest

Would it be best to consume a REST API using Javascript, AngularJS, TypeScript or just straightup using C# to consume the REST API.

I'm new to the REST API game and want to know, because I see so many ways to consume and I would like to know some of the most common ways. In particular is it better to use JAVASCRIPT or ANGULARJS to Consume a REST API and then pass it to C# code to work with or not?

ANY straight forward literature would be appreciated. For example how to consume a LINKED API using REST or consume FACEBOOK API using REST. Some sort of straight forward guide.

I'm going to quote Margin Call(2011) "Talk to me as if I am a golden retriever because I can assure you I did not get in the position I am today by being smart".

Comment: `most common ways to consume REST API's in a .NET environment? C# or JS or another language?` If you're using C# use WebClient/HttpClient class, if JS use AJAX. Which one to use? It really depends on your requirement. There are many API end points of facebook, so you have to be specific.

Comment: @Cheet Gohldstein A client of an API (especially REST) is (should be) platform/framework agnostic.  The only requirement is that the client knows how to make a HTTP request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So REST is a style of “implementation” and you can consume it anyhow i.e. You don’t consume Web api “using” REST, you implement it using REST. 
There is no good or bad here. If all you have to do is consume the API and do something in your c# app then I would just use the http client in your c# app. And you can use any language/framework not just c#/.net/angular, it just depends on your preference. Behind the scenes it’s just http calls.

Every framework/language has its own best practices for consuming REST.
As far as literature is concerned, you would find a lot of material online to understand REST principles.
But do note that they are design guidelines, not following some of them does not make your web api any lesser REST.

So you ll find differences in the implementation of different REST web apis. And that is why there is a always a doc usually that guides how to consume it, either a swagger style documentation or something custom.
Hope this gives you the 1000 feet overview to get yourself started on the right track.

Some good tools that you should have:
Postman
Fiddler